# My website wont scroll anymore after scrolling back up on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, vertical-scrolling

I just noticed a very weird behaviour on the homepage of my website on mobile devices. After scrolling down and then scrolling back up, the website stops responding to scroll events and the viewport just freezes. So the website just doesn't react anymore.

I have never experienced this before, I don't see any errors in the console. Does anyone have any idea what can be the cause of this?

My website: bailandolatino.be

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off the speed optimization plugin if you have any, and also disable the popup, I guess it is the problem that blocks the NL version, English works fine for me.